# Is there any way to perform a rolling rank in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking

I am trying to rank some values in one column over a rolling period of N days instead of having the ranking done over the entire set. I have seen several methods here using rolling_apply but I have read that this is no longer in python. For example, in the following table;
|        |    A |
|:-------|:-----|
|01-01-2013| 100|
|02-01-2013| 85 |
|03-01-2013| 110|
|04-01-2013|  60|
|05-01-2013|  20|
|06-01-2013|  40|

For the column A above, how can I have the rank as below for N = 3;

|  | A | Ranked_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2013 | 100 | NaN |
| 02-01-2013 | 85 | Nan |
| 03-01-2013 | 110 | 1 |
| 04-01-2013 | 60 | 3 |
| 05-01-2013 | 20 | 3 |
| 06-01-2013 | 40 | 2 |

Comment: [How to ask a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but without a "good pandas question" so you can verify the results, it will be difficult for anyone to show you.